# How to filter data using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created search filter but I am not able to type anything in search input why so ? I have created searchTermChanged method but why is it not working ? When user types in input field the projects should get filtered based on title.

Code:

```
    import Projects from '../../data/projects';

export default class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      search: '',
      projects: Projects
    }
  }

  searchTermChanged = (event) => {
    this.setState({ projects: this.state.projects.filter(val => 
      val.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) > -1 ) 
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <div className="header">
            <div className="md-form mt-0 customsearch">
                <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search projects" aria-label="Search"
                value={this.state.search}
                onChange={e => this.searchTermChanged(e.target.value)} 
                />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              {this.state.projects.map((val,index) => (
                <div class="col-3">
                  <Card title={val.title} by={val.by} blurb={val.blurb} 
                  url={val.url} funded={val.funded} backers={val.backers} imgurl={index}/>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.state.searchTerm` is always `''`. You don't update it anywhere

Comment: @apokryfos How should I modify the existing code so that searchterm also changes as well as projects get filtered based on search input. check updated code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure you're making correct use of the state.

```
import Projects from '../../data/projects';

export default class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      search: '',
      projects: Projects
    }
  }

  searchTermChanged = (search) => {
    this.setState({ 
      //Update the search state here.
       search, 
       //Use the current search state to filter
       projects: this.state.projects.filter(val => 
          val.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1 ) 
       }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <div className="header">
            <div className="md-form mt-0 customsearch">
                <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search projects" aria-label="Search"
                value={this.state.search}
                onChange={e => this.searchTermChanged(e.target.value)} 
                />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              {this.state.projects.map((val,index) => (
                <div class="col-3">
                  <Card title={val.title} by={val.by} blurb={val.blurb} 
                  url={val.url} funded={val.funded} backers={val.backers} imgurl={index}/>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be `projects: Projects.filter(val => val.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) > -1 )` instead of `projects: this.state.projects.filter(val => 
          val.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1 ) 
       }`

Comment: I was more concerned that if you used `this.state.search` it would filter by the previous search term since the current state is not updated yet.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you don't need to change the projects you can also do the bellow to simplify your logic:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      search: ''
    }
  }

render() {
    let {search} from this.state;
    let myProjects = projects.filter((p) => {
      p.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase) > -1
    });

return (
  <div>
      <div className="header">
        <div className="md-form mt-0 customsearch">
            <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search projects" aria-label="Search"
            value={this.state.search}
            onChange={e => this.setState({search: e.target.value})} 
            />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          {myProjects.map((val,index) => (
            <div class="col-3">
              <Card title={val.title} by={val.by} blurb={val.blurb} 
              url={val.url} funded={val.funded} backers={val.backers} imgurl={index}/>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to user Projects variable directly to filter otherwise filter changes will search on existing state. You need to set search value to refect what is your input

```
searchTermChanged = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    this.setState({
      projects: Projects.filter(val => 
      val.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.toLowerCase()) > -1 ),
      search: event <-- here
    })
  }
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fyf7fr

Answer (score 1):

You are not changing the state of "search".

Assuming u have an input like this:

```
<input type="text" id="whatever" className="whatever" onChange={(event) => props.searchTermChanged(e.target.value)} />
```

you can change your method searchTermChanged

```
searchTermChanged = (value) => {
this.setState({search: value});
    this.setState({ projects: this.state.projects.filter(val => 
      val.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1 ) 
    });
  }
```

The reason why u use "value" instead of "this.state.search" here "indexOf(value.toLowerCase())" its because setState is asynchronous and you can reach that piece of code with state outdated. And you are sure that "value" has the right value.